# ODBC Driver Installation in Databricks

Tags: odbc, azure-databricks, pyodbc

I am trying to install ODBC driver in azure databricks. But I am facing below error message,

sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required

Approaches that I followed to install:
Cluster Runtime Version: 13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12)

1. Installed pyodbc to the cluster itself from pypi.
2. Used below script to install ODBC driver 17

```
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

3. Received error

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
```

4. Then Tried removing sudo. Received error E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
5. Tried to run it as root user with sudo -s, received error E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)

Please let me know how to resolve this issue, as I am struck in this issue for multiple days.

Comment: Is it shared UC cluster?

Comment: It is all purpose cluster, using it in shared mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this on the shared clusters, at least not in the interactive mode, because users are isolated from each other. You need to put actual commands (see below) into the init script and attach it to your cluster (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/init-scripts/cluster-scoped.html) for details):

Code of the init script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

curl --silent https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
# Install msodbcsql17
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get --quiet ---yes install msodbcsql17
```

Comment: I am facing this error after setting up init script with the code mentioned above, {
  "init_scripts": {
    "reported_for_node": node_id,
    "global": [],
    "cluster": [
      {
        "workspace": {
          "destination": "/Users/<user_name>/init_script.sh"
        },
        "status": "FAILED_EXECUTION",
        "execution_duration_seconds": 1,
        "error_message": "Script exit status is non-zero"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Typo in the file name resolved the issue. Accepted the answer as well. Thank you!